# Best practice in laravel blade use of {{ }}

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Which of those two is the best practice using blade in laravel:

`<p>{{ $person->name }} {{ $person->surname }}</p>` or `<p>{{ $person->name . ' ' . $person->surname }}</p>`

Thanks!

Comment: I'd personally advocate for the first. Or making an Eloquent accessor that combines the two so you can just do `{{ $person->fullName }}`.

Comment: @Vucko Does anyone *actually* say po-tah-toe?

Comment: Dunno, it's just a saying :D @ceejayoz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither is a good option because in case one is empty (first or last name) - you will have an extra space that doesn't mean anything.

Best practises are:

1) Implement a method like getName() on your Person class that does the concatenation for you. Eg.

```
public function getName()
{
    return implode(' ', array_filter([$this->name, $this->surname])));
}
```

And in your template it would become just `<p>{{ $person->getName() }}</p>`

2) If you have more attributes that require alteration before rendering - a common practise is to extract them all to a presenter class (that's a design pattern). Then your template would look like `<p>{{ $person->presenter()->getName() }}</p>`. But if it's just the name - you are probably fine just keeping it in the Person class.

Comment: To add to this, I would make this a dynamic attribute by changing the function name to `getNameAttribute` so you can access it like `$person->name`

Answer (score 0):

It's usually all down to personal preference, Both are perfectly valid ways to do it, I like keeping everything seperate because at least for me (not everyone might think this is easier/cleaner), it becomes so much easier to add extra markup like this;

```
<b>{{ $person->surname }}</b>, <small class='text-muted'>{{ $person->name }}</small>
```

I always like to think of it in terms of dumb days, if you're having one of those days where you just can't think, which is easier to read for you :)